# Close all open http requests of all clients generated by nswagstudio

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nswagstudio

I want to close all open http requests of all clients that are genereated by nswagstudio automatically, if an action happens. I generate for each controller an own client.

Currently I have ten clients.

How I can do this for all ten clients automatically?

Comment: can you share  code  to help you better, If you have subscription on http calls then by unsubscribing to that subscription can cancel the http calls.

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't share code because of privacy reasons.